# full calendar ajax event insert not rendering on calendar

Tags: jquery, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I make post request in laravel and get this object in response:

```
{id: 11, title: "dummy", allDay: false, start: "2021-06-12T19:23:00+00:00", end: "2021-06-12T19:28:00+00:00", …}
allDay: false
color: "#f05050"
end: "2021-06-12T19:28:00+00:00"
id: 11
start: "2021-06-12T19:23:00+00:00"
title: "dummy"
__proto__: Object
```

Now to create new Event in full calendar

```
var newEvent = aboveobject;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent);
```

Event is not showing in calendar

edit fiddle

```html
<html lang="en"><head>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-mSYUmp1HYZDFaVKK//63EcZq4iFWFjxSL+Z3T/aCt4IO9Cejm03q3NKKYN6pFQzY0SBOr8h+eCIAZHPXcpZaNw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-T/tUfKSV1bihCnd+MxKD0Hm1uBBroVYBOYSk1knyvQ9VyZJpc/ALb4P0r6ubwVPSGB2GvjeoMAJJImBG12TiaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Olpary8p2p3xQOLtDnT4irmxg6IKMvvucL1LIDF5">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>
       
<div class="modal fade" id="add_event_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add_event_modal_title" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="add_event_modal_title">Create a Event</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="create_event">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Olpary8p2p3xQOLtDnT4irmxg6IKMvvucL1LIDF5">  
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Title">Title:</label>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required="">
            
        
         
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <strong> Start Date : </strong>  
            <input class="date form-control" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" required="">   
          
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <strong> Start Time: </strong>  
         <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" type="time" name="starttime" required="">
    
         </div>
       
        </div>
       
        <div class="row" style="align-items:flex-end;">
        
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         
          <strong> Duration: </strong>  
           <select name="hours" class="form-control" required="">
           <option value="0">0 hours</option>
           <option value="1">1 hours</option>
           <option value="2">2 hours</option>
           </select>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <select name="minutes" class="form-control" required="">
           <option value="5">5 minutes</option>
           <option value="10">10 minutes</option>
           <option value="15">15 minutes</option>
           <option value="20">20 minutes</option>
           </select>
         </div>
      
        </div>
        

        
          <div class="form-group">
          <strong> E-mail: </strong>  
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" required="">
           
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <strong> Mobile Numbers: </strong>  
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobileno" required="">
          
          </div>
          
         
      </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="add_event(this)" class="btn btn-danger">Add Event</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card container">
                <div class="card-header row align-items-baseline">
                <div class="col-8">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                Meeting Scheduler
                </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <button type="button" onclick="add_event(this)" class="btn btn-danger">
      Add Event
    </button>
    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="calendar-qPSyHH6w" class="fc fc-ltr fc-unthemed"><div class="fc-toolbar"><div class="fc-left"><div class="fc-button-group"><button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span></button><button type="button" class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right"><span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow"></span></button></div><button type="button" class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-disabled" disabled="disabled">today</button></div><div class="fc-right"><div class="fc-button-group"><button type="button" class="fc-month-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active">month</button><button type="button" class="fc-agendaWeek-button fc-button fc-state-default">week</button><button type="button" class="fc-agendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">day</button></div></div><div class="fc-center"><h2>June 2021</h2></div><div class="fc-clear"></div></div><div class="fc-view-container" style=""><div class="fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view" style=""><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-widget-header"><div class="fc-row fc-widget-header"><table><thead><tr><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun">Sun</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon">Mon</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue">Tue</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed">Wed</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu">Thu</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri">Fri</th><th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat">Sat</th></tr></thead></table></div></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="fc-widget-content"><div class="fc-day-grid-container" style=""><div class="fc-day-grid"><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 67px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2021-05-30"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2021-05-31"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2021-06-01"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2021-06-02"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2021-06-03"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2021-06-04"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2021-06-05"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2021-05-30">30</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2021-05-31">31</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2021-06-01">1</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2021-06-02">2</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2021-06-03">3</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2021-06-04">4</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2021-06-05">5</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td rowspan="3"></td><td rowspan="3"></td><td rowspan="3"></td><td class="fc-event-container fc-limited"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="background-color:#f05050;border-color:#f05050"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">6:22p</span> <span class="fc-title">Event 3</span></div></a></td><td class="fc-more-cell" rowspan="1"><div><a class="fc-more">+3 more</a></div></td><td rowspan="3"></td><td rowspan="3"></td><td rowspan="3"></td></tr><tr class="fc-limited"><td class="fc-event-container"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="background-color:#f05050;border-color:#f05050"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">7p</span> <span class="fc-title">Event 4</span></div></a></td></tr><tr class="fc-limited"><td class="fc-event-container"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" style="background-color:#f05050;border-color:#f05050"><div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">7:30p</span> <span class="fc-title">Event 2</span></div></a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 67px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2021-06-06"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2021-06-07"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2021-06-08"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2021-06-09"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2021-06-10"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2021-06-11"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-12"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2021-06-06">6</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2021-06-07">7</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2021-06-08">8</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2021-06-09">9</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2021-06-10">10</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2021-06-11">11</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-12">12</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 67px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-13"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-14"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-15"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-16"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-06-17"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-06-18"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-19"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-13">13</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-14">14</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-15">15</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-16">16</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-06-17">17</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-06-18">18</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-19">19</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 67px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-20"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-21"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-22"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-23"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-06-24"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-06-25"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-26"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-20">20</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-21">21</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-22">22</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-23">23</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2021-06-24">24</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2021-06-25">25</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2021-06-26">26</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 67px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-27"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-28"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-29"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-30"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-01"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-02"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-03"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2021-06-27">27</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2021-06-28">28</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2021-06-29">29</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2021-06-30">30</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-01">1</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-02">2</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-03">3</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 70px;"><div class="fc-bg"><table><tbody><tr><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-04"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-05"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-06"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-07"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-08"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-09"></td><td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-10"></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="fc-content-skeleton"><table><thead><tr><td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-04">4</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-05">5</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-06">6</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-07">7</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-08">8</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-09">9</td><td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2021-07-10">10</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>
                    
                   
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>


       <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#calendar-qPSyHH6w').fullCalendar({"header":{"left":"prev,next today","center":"title","right":"month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"},"eventLimit":true,"events":[{"id":1,"title":"Event 2","allDay":false,"start":"2021-06-02T19:30:00+00:00","end":"2021-06-02T20:30:00+00:00","color":"#f05050"},{"id":6,"title":"Event 3","allDay":false,"start":"2021-06-02T18:22:00+00:00","end":"2021-06-02T18:27:00+00:00","color":"#f05050"},{"id":7,"title":"Event 4","allDay":false,"start":"2021-06-02T19:00:00+00:00","end":"2021-06-02T19:20:00+00:00","color":"#f05050"}]});
    });
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">  
        $('#startdate').datepicker({ 
            autoclose: true,   
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'  
         });
         $('#enddate').datepicker({ 
            autoclose: true,   
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
         }); 


function show_event_modal(){
    $('#add_event_modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
}

function add_event(button){
    var event = {
allDay: false,
color: "#f05050",
end: "2021-06-12T19:28:00+00:00",
id: 11,
start: "2021-06-12T19:23:00+00:00",
title: "dummy"};
console.log(event);


$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
    }




    </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

       
</body></html>
```

Comment: Working fine for me . Are you seeing any error in browser console ?

Comment: @Swati No I dont

Comment: Not reproducible - that event data works fine. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEeqBPN?editable=true&editors=001 . Presumably you have some sort of issue which isn't apparent from the detail above.

Comment: @ADyson added complete code and reproducible example

Comment: @Swati added complete code

Comment: You have different ids it should be `$('#calendar-qPSyHH6w').fullCalendar(...`

Comment: @Swati  thanks a lot , i was banging my head since a long time ,  but i  still dont know why each time I load the page different id is allotted to calendar

Comment: @ADyson can u help me why different id is alloted as u are from php background i am using this https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar

Comment: `i still dont know why each time I load the page different id is allotted to calendar` ...no idea, presumably something in the PHP does it, I'm not going to poke through the whole github repo to find out, sorry. But that library is years out of date, it uses an ancient version of fullCalendar and doesn't really bring any particular benefits as far as I can see. fullCalendar loaded directly from the JS would be a) more up to date, b) more efficient, c) more predictable, and d) just as easy to hook up to an event feed etc on the server side. Latest docs and downloads: https://fullcalendar.io

Comment: No problem thanks a lot

Comment: With the help of fellow so i solve like this `$('div[id^="calendar-"]').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent);`